# Check if time range is between another time range

Tags: sql-server

Im stuck in solving something. How can I check if a time range is between another time range?

For example how can I check if 11:00AM - 12:00PM is between 9:30AM - 2PM?
I need this in developing timekeeping system to check if the filed Sick Leave of an employee covers his scheduled break time.

Im using SQL Server 2008

```
declare @timefrom datetime
declare @timeto datetime
declare @timefromBreak datetime
declare @timetoBreak datetime

set @timefrom = cast('01/21/2015 11:30:00' as datetime)
set @timeto = cast('01/21/2015 14:00:00' as datetime)
set @timefromBreak = cast('01/21/2015 11:00:00' as datetime)
set @timetoBreak = cast('01/21/2015 12:00:00' as datetime)

select 
case when ((@timefromBreak between @timefrom and @timeto) AND (@timetoBreak between @timefrom and @timeto)) then
(datediff(hour, @timefrom,@timeto) - datediff(hour,@timefromBreak,@timetoBreak))

else datediff(hour, @timefrom,@timeto) 

end as TotalLeaveHours
```

here is my example.. im trying to get the total leave hours an employee filed for his Leave.

The logic is that i will get the total leave hours not including the break time (if and only if the leave time range covers the break time.)

So if an employee filed a leave for 11:30PM to 2:00PM and his scheduled break time is 11:00Am to 12:00PM. The total leave hours should only be 2Hours.

11:30AM to 12:00PM should not be counted for the total leave hours since his scheduled time is 11:00AM to 12:00PM..

Comment: What is your tables look like ? What is the data and what output you expecting ? Most importantly what did you tried ?

Comment: There's a remarkably simple rule for determining overlaps - two time periods overlap if the first starts before the second ends *and* the second starts before the first ends - however, based on what you've posted as an answer, it seems you're actually trying to do some calculations around the overlaps - so could you edit your question and add some sample data and expected results - we don't need a lot, but more than a *single* example would probably be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This computes the time difference (in minutes at the moment<sup>1</sup>) and tries to take care of all possible overlaps:

```
declare @timefrom datetime
declare @timeto datetime
declare @timefromBreak datetime
declare @timetoBreak datetime

select @timefrom = '2015-01-21T11:30:00',@timeto = '2015-01-21T14:00:00',
       @timefromBreak = '2015-01-21T11:00:00',@timetoBreak = '2015-01-21T12:00:00'

select DATEDIFF(minute,@timefrom,@timeto) -
CASE WHEN @timeFrom < @timeToBreak AND @timefromBreak < @timeTo THEN
    DATEDIFF(minute,
        CASE WHEN @timeFrom > @timeFromBreak THEN @timeFrom ELSE @timeFromBreak END,
        CASE WHEN @timeTo < @timeToBreak THEN @timeTo ELSE @timeToBreak END
    ) ELSE 0 END
```

Hopefully, you can see the basic logic - we always compute the time difference - and then we check whether an overlap exists. Only if an overlap exists do we need to adjust the total time, and we do that using a couple of `CASE` expressions to account for when the break time and the leave time *partially* overlap or entirely overlap.

(If SQL Server had `MIN` and `MAX` functions that worked against multiple arguments instead of multiple rows, then the later `CASE` expressions would have just been `MAX(@timeFrom,@timeFromBreak)` and `MIN(@timeTo,@timeToBreak)`)

---

<sup>1</sup>Since in some of your examples you seem to be working with e.g. 2.5 hours, I though it would be safer to work in minutes and let you perform any final adjustment/rounding down/up as a final step, separate from these calculations

Comment: and then i will just divide it to 60 to get the hour? I changed the @timefrom to  '2015-01-21T09:30:00' and I get a whole number 3 instead of 3.5 (with decimal)

Comment: @bob_tiamsic - if you take the current result and divide by 60 (an integer divide) you'll get hours but you'll lose any fractional portion (e.g. 150/60 = 2) and I wasn't sure that that was your overall desired result or whether you wanted to retain the fractional parts or round up

Comment: got it! tried to cast( as decimal(3,2)) thank you very much! this is so helpful and informative! God bless sir!

Answer (score 0):

4 is the total leave hours..

Sorry for making confusions..I need to get the total number of hours..I tried it and i think there will be no conflict if the leave time range will cover the entire break time..how ever if only part of the break time will be covered, the first condition will be false..

if the employee's break schedule is 11:00AM to 12:00PM, then the leave he filed is from 11:30AM to 2:00Pm the Total Leave Hours should return only 3 hours, instead of 2.5hours.

in my testing,

```
    declare @timefrom datetime
declare @timeto datetime
declare @timefromBreak datetime
declare @timetoBreak datetime

set @timefrom = cast('01/21/2015 11:30:00' as datetime)
set @timeto = cast('01/21/2015 14:00:00' as datetime)
set @timefromBreak = cast('01/21/2015 11:00:00' as datetime)
set @timetoBreak = cast('01/21/2015 12:00:00' as datetime)

select 
case when ((@timefromBreak between @timefrom and @timeto) AND (@timetoBreak between @timefrom and @timeto)) then
(datediff(hour, @timefrom,@timeto) - datediff(hour,@timefromBreak,@timetoBreak))

else datediff(hour, @timefrom,@timeto) 

end as TotalLeaveHours
```

this returns 3 hours because it doesn't meet the first condition in Select Case statement.